# Upgrade OTRS 6.0 - /opt/otrs/bin/c CPU usage

Tags: perl, otrs

OTRS 6.0 - /opt/otrs/bin/c CPU usage

Hi everyone,

On OTRS 6.0, the /opt/otrs/bin/c processus use 100% when login to otrs/index.pl :

```
3104 apache    20   0  441496  79904   6308 R 100.0  0.2   0:06.05 /opt/otrs/bin/c
```

The web page is displayed after 4.1 min, after than process /opt/otrs/bin/c is finished and OTRS respond quickly.

I don't kown if correlation exist, but I found this old threads :

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=821848
https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2015-8853

I use perl v5.16.3 on CentOS 7.6

> If the problem concerne perl version (regex issue), what the best practice to upgrade version (not in the official repo) ?
>
> By scl, Redhat write "Unfortunately, it’s not easy to solve these issues, because we would lose the ability to not influence the base system underneath, the main feature of Software Collections technology."
> By compilation (cpan...), broke yum dependance and install many build packages

OTRS Perl script use #!/usr/bin/perl shebang.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar issue with last version of OTRS (6 patch level 19), perl 5.16.3 on CentOS 7.6.

Randomly on my side I can't open the login screen due to /opt/otrs/bin/c hanged process (but no CPU utilization).

If I do a restart of Apache httpd service it doesn't restart immediatly but it waits the end of that process.

Today I found a "dirty way" to upgrade perl to 5.26 and to install all requested perl modules (by OTRS).

I have been testing the solution for a couple of days and it seems to work regularly. Unfortunately the problem is totally random so I will have to wait more days.

Here the workaround (CentOS 7.6)

## Install centos-release-scl and some other stuff

yum update

yum install centos-release-scl

yum install rh-perl526

yum install gcc

yum install openssl-devel.x86_64

yum install rh-perl526-perl-CPAN.noarch

yum install rh-perl526-perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64

yum install rh-perl526-perl-Encode-devel.x86_64

yum install expat-devel.x86_64

yum install rh-perl526-mod_perl.x86_64

yum install rh-perl526-perl-DateTime.x86_64

yum install rh-perl526-perl-YAML.noarch

## Enable "special" bash with perl 5.26

scl enable rh-perl526 bash

cpan Crypt::Eksblowfish::Bcrypt

cpan Crypt::SSLeay

cpan Encode::HanExtra

cpan IO::Socket::SSL

cpan JSON::XS

cpan Mail::IMAPClient

cpan Authen::SASL

cpan Net::DNS

cpan Template

cpan Text::CSV_XS

cpan XML::LibXML

cpan XML::LibXSLT

cpan XML::Parser

cpan Net::LDAP

cpan YAML::XS

### check required modules by OTRS

/opt/otrs/bin/otrs.CheckModules.pl

## To make perl 5.26 persistent for all users and cron

### append lines to /etc/profile

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/usr/lib64
export PATH=/opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/usr/local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

## append lines to /etc/environment

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/usr/lib64
PATH=/opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/usr/local/bin:/opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Comment: I've got the problem again. "Solution" is not valid.